# How to set boundaries for a button splash effect in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

When I press an IconButton inside a container, the splash effect is drawn outside the container so it kind of "overflows". How can I set boundaries to limit the area where the splash effect is drawn?

My hierarchy looks like this and I want to limit the splash effect inside the container widget.

```
- Expanded
-- Listview

- Container
-- Row
--- IconButton[]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the solution while writing this question so I'll just leave the answer here in case someone else runs in to the same problem.

I had to wrap the container into a ClipPath widget to limit the area of the splash effect.

```
- Expanded
-- Listview

- ClipPath (add this)
-- Container
--- Row
---- IconButton[]
```

[image]

Comment: For your information, it's not material that does this. But ClipPath used by material.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Thanks for clarifying. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the splash area, Splash area in above button image is cropped on top and bottom, I'm looking for a small splash circle which does not get cropped.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use an InkWell widget with an Icon as the child. As Flutter docs states

> [Clipping to a path is expensive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html)

You can use onTap() property to put your function and you can use `borderRadius` property to give your splash a circle shape.

Circle splash InkWell

```
Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            onTap: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.timer),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Or you can use the default shape without borderRadius which is also cool :}

```
Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.timer),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just change splashRadius on IconButton property. Ex.

```
IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.timer),
      splashRadius: 24.0,
    ),
```

From doc: `If null, default splash radius of [Material.defaultSplashRadius] is used.` which is 35